# Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop. Days of the week

Tags: reactjs

The code doesn't break the app, but the console show me this error.

Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.

```
render() {
        const daysOfWeek = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"];
        const listDays = daysOfWeek.map((dayName) =>
            <Table.HeaderCell>{dayName}</Table.HeaderCell> 
        );
```

And

```
return (
   <Table.Row>{listDays}</Table.Row>
)
```

Please somebody can help

Comment: Well the warning is pretty clear, and a quick google search would show tons of info about this warning. `.map()` returns an array, so each JSX parent element returned needs an identify key, e.g. `<Table.HeaderCell key={dayName}>{dayName}</Table.HeaderCell>`. do some research into why array elements needs keys and what they're used for in React

Comment: Almost simple like this, I find in documentation 
in reac page this, https://codepen.io/gaearon/pen/jrXYRR?editors=0011

Answer (score 0):

My solution is:

```
render() {
        const daysOfWeek = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"];
        const listDays = daysOfWeek.map((dayName) =>
            <Table.HeaderCell key={dayName.toString()}>{dayName}</Table.HeaderCell> 
        );
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem is Table.HeaderCell is repeated multiple time because of the rendering inside the loop so another solution could be

```
render() {
        const daysOfWeek = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"];
        const listDays = daysOfWeek.map((dayName, index) =>
            <Table.HeaderCell key={index}>{dayName}</Table.HeaderCell> 
        );
```

Answer (score 0):

Fabricio, do it like this so that the key remains unique all the time.

```
render() {
        const daysOfWeek = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"];
        const listDays = daysOfWeek.map((dayName, index) =>
            <Table.HeaderCell key={index}>{dayName}</Table.HeaderCell> 
        );
```